# Gettin this error "Custom tool error: Unable to create DiscoveryClientProtocol from reference map file"

Tags: c#, web-services, migration, service

I am trying to open my project (that is in ASP.Net 2.0 ) in VSTS 2008. Earlier i used VS 2005. When i try to build the project it gives me the error "Unable to create DiscoveryClientProtocol from reference map file"? I tried to figure out this error and found that there is some problem with web reference to the web service i am calling.

I cannot share the code but i need a solution. If some one have faced such issue please help....

Comment: Have you tried re-ading the web-reference from scratch? Deleting it? How about using wsdl.exe (or wse*wsdl.exe or scvutil.exe) at the command line?

Comment: I tried wsdl.exe in command prompt but i get HTTP status 403: Forbidden.